# firestore PERMISSION_DENIED when slow internet

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When slow internet connection i am getting `PERMISSION_DENIED`

> [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(lists/t8hDrmGrKrjdjIrO7dt8/items order by che, ca, cre, **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

the database structure is:

```
/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}
```

the `lists` document has a `col` array containing uid's allowed to read and write to the `items` collection

To accomplish that, i use the next rule:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/lists/$(listId)).data.col
```

And the next android code:

```
mRef.document(glist.getId()).set( glist );
enterList( glist);
```

Correct me if i am wrong, the cause for this sometimes `PERMISSION_DENIED` error, is the case when the `lists` document is created **after** trying to Read from it, causing the rule to break since there is no document

The way i solved it was by waiting for the `lists` document to be created before trying to view its content using the next code:

```
mRef.document(glist.getId()).set( glist ).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        enterList( glist);
    }
} );
```

This seemed to solve the problem but then a realized that the `addOnSuccessListener` can only be fired when ONLINE, causing it to hang when OFFLINE.

What are my other options to solve this problem while keeping the rule?

Comment: If the read depends on a previous write, you should only attach the listener once the previous write has completed. But that should not require a success listener, as indeed those check for server-side commit. Can you show the code that *isn't* working too?

Comment: I added the code that isn't working also

Comment: Hmmm... that looks fine. The `set()` should have been committed locally before the next line runs, and have been sent off to the server. But clearly, it isn't committed there in time before you're attaching the listener. :-/

Comment: Not sure i understand. To describe one use case that can more easily be replicated (since it is hard to replicate slow internet connection), i go into airplane mode --> execute the code without the listener --> exit the airplane mode ==> sometimes (not always) i am getting the PERMISSION_DENIED and cannot see any added items, while writing no problem (since only query listener failed)